# Documentation percentage images

Tags: documentation

In many open-source repositories I see images like this below.

[image: logo]

Are these built by some specific library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that a library made it easy to make.
But you can do this kind of image yourself with probably any language.

In your case it's probably PHP generating the image.

http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-png.php